# Cannot create an instance of "TriggerActionCollection"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following:

`XAML`

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"        

 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding State}">
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding State}" />
       </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I've also added a reference to both:

`Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`

`System.Windows.Interactivity`

Initially, I was using `Blend` to reference these two but after some reading online I removed it.

I'm left with the above error message.

Would anyone know the reason?

Comment: Here is a discussion about this symptom. Don't know if it helps in your case, the solution is using the latest version of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` installed on the system.

Comment: Thanks @kennyzx. I think you have accidentally forgotten to provide the link?

Comment: Oh, my apologies. [here](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/440478) it is.

Comment: @kennyzx Thank you. Is there a way I can definitively find the latest version? The `Blend` one I had seems to have the highest version number `(3.0.40218.0)` compared to the ones I randomly found through Google.

Comment: I search in `C:\Program Files (x86)` and yes, 3.0.40218 shipped with Blend is the latest version...so I am out of clue.

Comment: It's really weird. I restarted my computer and the error has gone away.. not sure how long that will last. I put the `Blend` version back in.